# How do I add the soil moisture data I am trying to get onto my Google drive?

Tags: google-earth-engine, code-review, soil, google-drive

Here is my code
How do I add the soil moisture data I am trying to get onto my Google drive?

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NASA_USDA/HSL/SMAP_soil_moisture')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2017-04-01', '2017-04-30'));
var soilMoisture = dataset.select('ssm');
var soilMoistureVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 28.0,
  palette: ['0300ff', '418504', 'efff07', 'efff07', 'ff0303'],
};
Map.setCenter(-6.746, 46.529, 2);
Map.addLayer(soilMoisture, soilMoistureVis, 'Soil Moisture');
```

Answer (score 2):

`soilMoisture` is an image collection. You will have to export each image in the the collection separately. Here's how you could do it:

```
soilMoisture
  .aggregate_array('system:index') // Get a list of unique ids
  .evaluate(function (indexes) { // Turn this into a client-side list
    indexes.map(exportImage) // Export all images
  })

function exportImage(index) {
  var image = soilMoisture // Find the image with this unique id
    .filterMetadata('system:index', 'equals', index)
    .first()
  Export.image.toDrive({ // Export it
    image: image,
    description: index,
    scale: 27829
  })
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/2e9adee99d5683f5551741a907bf2e16